# Remove a part of a string, but only when it is at the end of the string

Tags: php, string, replace, preg-replace

I need to remove a substring of a string, but only when it is at the END of the string.

for example, removing 'string' at the end of the following strings  :

```
"this is a test string" ->  "this is a test "
"this string is a test string" - > "this string is a test "
"this string is a test" -> "this string is a test"
```

Any idea's ? Probably some kind of preg_replace, but how??

Comment: You might find [`s($str)->replaceSuffix('string')`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/ea3e40132e9d4ce27da337dae6286f2478b15f56/src/Str.php#L442) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str).

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You'll note the use of the `$` character, which denotes the end of a string:

```
$new_str = preg_replace('/string$/', '', $str);
```

If the string is a user supplied variable, it is a good idea to run it through [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/preg_quote) first:

```
$remove = $_GET['remove']; // or whatever the case may be
$new_str = preg_replace('/'. preg_quote($remove, '/') . '$/', '', $str);
```

Comment: will preg_quote/preg_replace work with non ASCII (say UTF-8) strings as well ? i.e. to say are `preg_*` function families aware of encoding ? What about `[^[:alnum:]]` character class ?

Comment: This doesn't remove the space before "string" if it were to exist. You could also just use substring on the last 6 characters, compare them to "string", and if it's a match, substring them out. It'd be much faster than Regex.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer. Using preg_replace for this task is ugly as hell, wrong in logic, and a total waste of server energy/time/cycles (yes, it matters, you pay your hosting more because 10000000 of other users' web pages use preg_replace instead of substr)

Answer (score 36):

Using regexp may fails if the substring has special characters.

The following will work with any strings and follows conventions used by built-in string functions:

```php
function right_trim(string $haystack, string $needle): string {
    $needle_length = strlen($needle);
    if (substr($haystack, -$needle_length) === $needle) {
        return substr($haystack, 0, -$needle_length);
    }
    return $haystack;
}
```

Comment: the last bit can be simply `$str = substr($str, 0, -strlen($substring));` upvoted as good alternative for regex. I came up with same answer for my problem. I would use pure string functions over `preg_*` families anytime if it serves my purpose

Comment: a simple and smart solution for a supposedly simple problem without using regular expressions. thanks

Comment: As some say "if your solution requires regex, now you have two problems".  So for the fun of it I wanted to solve this problem for non-regex and I had come with exactly this and @Sudhi's comment before seeing your answer.  The little piece I wasn't aware of was that you can place "-" to negate rather than multiplying by -1.  So thanks.

Comment: Just a note: should use mb_* functions to be safe for special char (eg: áéã, etc)

Comment: @Sudhi, thanks for the tip! I've edited the question to use it. I've also reformatted the code so that it's a function and it follows conventions used by built-in string functions. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 13):

I wrote these two function for left and right trim of a string:

```
/**
 * @param string    $str           Original string
 * @param string    $needle        String to trim from the end of $str
 * @param bool|true $caseSensitive Perform case sensitive matching, defaults to true
 * @return string Trimmed string
 */
function rightTrim($str, $needle, $caseSensitive = true)
{
    $strPosFunction = $caseSensitive ? "strpos" : "stripos";
    if ($strPosFunction($str, $needle, strlen($str) - strlen($needle)) !== false) {
        $str = substr($str, 0, -strlen($needle));
    }
    return $str;
}

/**
 * @param string    $str           Original string
 * @param string    $needle        String to trim from the beginning of $str
 * @param bool|true $caseSensitive Perform case sensitive matching, defaults to true
 * @return string Trimmed string
 */
function leftTrim($str, $needle, $caseSensitive = true)
{
    $strPosFunction = $caseSensitive ? "strpos" : "stripos";
    if ($strPosFunction($str, $needle) === 0) {
        $str = substr($str, strlen($needle));
    }
    return $str;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I suppose you could use a [**regular expression**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php), which would match `string` and, then, *end of string*, coupled with the [**`preg_replace()`**](https://www.php.net/preg_replace) function.

Something like this should work just fine :

```
$str = "this is a test string";
$new_str = preg_replace('/string$/', '', $str);
```

Notes :

- `string` matches... well... `string`
- and `$` means *end of string*

For more informations, you can read the [**Pattern Syntax**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) section of the PHP manual.

Answer (score 2):

preg_replace  and this pattern :  /string\z/i

\z  means end of the string

http://tr.php.net/preg_replace

Answer (score 0):

IF you don't mind about performance AND the part of the string could be placed only at the end of string, THEN you can do this:

```
$string = "this is a test string";
$part = "string";
$string = implode( $part, array_slice( explode( $part, $string ), 0, -1 ) );
echo $string;
// OUTPUT: "this is a test "
```

Answer (score 0):

@Skrol29's answer is the best, but here it is in function form and using the ternary operator:

```
if (!function_exists('str_ends_with')) {
    function str_ends_with($haystack, $suffix) {
        $length = strlen( $suffix );
        if( !$length ) {
            return true;
        }
        return substr( $haystack, -$length ) === $suffix;
    }
}

if (!function_exists('remove_suffix')) {
    function remove_suffix ($string, $suffix) {
        return str_ends_with($string, $suffix) ? substr($string, 0, strlen($string) - strlen($suffix)) : $string;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP 8 version

```
function removePostfix(string $haystack, string $needle): string
{
    if (str_ends_with($haystack, $needle)) {
        return substr($haystack, 0, strlen($haystack) - strlen($needle));
    }


    return $haystack;
}
```