# Rtrim in php remove last <br>

Tags: php

I've a very strange problem. my script cut the last `>` and i don't know why.

```
<?php

$string = "<a href='#'>Test</a>" . "<br>";
$string = rtrim($string, "<br>");

var_dump($string);

// OUTPUT

string '<a href='#'>Test</a' (length=19)

// INSTEAD

string '<a href='#'>Test</a>' (length=20)
```

I need to remove THE LAST `<br>` in the string (if present) and only if is the tail of the string.

Example:

```
$string = "<a>CC</a><br><a>CC</a>" //is ok
$string = "<a>CC</a><br><a>CC</a><br>" // --> <a>CC</a><br><a>CC</a>
```

Comment: `rtrim` doesn't treat its second argument as a string, but as a list of characters. So it'll remove all instances of of `<`, `b`, `r`, and `>` from the end of the string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove a part of a string, but only when it is at the end of the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573334/remove-a-part-of-a-string-but-only-when-it-is-at-the-end-of-the-string)

Comment: Ops i've always used Rtrim in bad way then!! :(

Comment: @GiuseppeLodiRizzini Yep, you did. I have corrected it. Feel free to use my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second parameter is not a delimiter but a **character mask**. So, it will definitely trim off any of the strings, individually.

> You can also specify the characters you want to strip, by means of the character_mask parameter. Simply list all characters that you want to be stripped. With .. you can specify a range of characters.

You have to remove it with either `str_replace()`, if there's only one `<br>`:

```
str_replace("<br>", "", $string);
```

Or you need to use [RegExp](https://regex101.com/r/ZxZTIB/1):

```
preg_replace('/<br>$/', "", $string);
```

Comment: No, i've not only one <br>... i can have other inside string. My goal is to remove only <br> at the end of the string (if present)

Comment: @GiuseppeLodiRizzini Use the RegExp version then... That removes only one at the end.